# Connect to Database with Connection String to use LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a connection string and I want to use LINQ to query a remote database. In the Microsoft example they use the `DataContext` class. However the `DataContext` does not appear in Intellisense. It says that it uses 'System.Data.Linq` but I am not seeing that either. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350721(v=vs.110).aspx

Is there a Hello World example for using a connection string and LINQ?

```
public void SimpleQuery()
{
    var connectionString = @"Server=10.1.10.1;database=Mydatabase;uid=myusername;password=mypassword;";
    DataContext dc = new DataContext(connectionString);

    var q =
        from n in dc.table
        select n;

    Console.WriteLine(n);
}
```

Comment: Have you [added a reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757637/cannot-find-using-system-data-linq) to the System.Data.Linq assembly?

Comment: I added the reference and I can see it now, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, that is **not** how it works or at least it is not that simple.

In order to be able to  run linq queries against your `DB`, first you need to map your db tables to dot net classes.

You can do that in various ways, for example you can use [`Linq to Sql`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976(v=vs.110).aspx), or `Entity framework.`

For `EF`, you need to decide which `EF` approach you are going to use (`Model First`,`Code First` etc.) Then you should configure your settings and create your db context.Take a look at [Entity Framework documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907) for more details...