# Can not add System.Data.Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-assembly

For some reason I can't reference System.Data.Linq. I added the reference in References but it doesn't work in the code.

I need access to System.Data.Linq.Mapping (didn't include it in the screenshot but that is the needed assembly).

I already tried searching the different questions regarding this, but the answers given there didn't work.

[image: System.Data.Linq missing]

Comment: What framework you are using

Comment: Try re-change target framework for your project. Go to Proporties > Application > Target Framework change to another  than used now, and next change it back.

Comment: I know its different dll..

Comment: @TimSchmelter according to OP capture, he already added the reference to the project, so I think it wouldn't fit the marked duplicate

Comment: @Pikoh: it's still a duplicate question. Or what makes it different? If this is different OP has forgotten to tell us the difference.

Comment: I tried following the answers in the other question but it didn't work.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Well..technicaly the question is a duplicate, is the solution provided there what wouldn't fit

Comment: I added the reference by rightclicking References. I also tried setting Copy Local to True. Still not working. Also tried browsing for the DLL and add it that way. Not working.

Comment: Try to add this to the web.config: `<add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>`

Comment: What worked was @M.Wiśnicki s answer! Please add is as a solution so that I can mark it.

Comment: Or add it (also) to the duplicate question as additional answer ;)

Comment: As suggested @TimSchmelter, I'm added to the duplicate question as additional answer

Answer (score -3):

Right click your solution/project. Click Add Reference and search for

System.Data.Linq  and add the reference there and it should compile.
If still not working : Check "Copy Local, True" in the Properties pane for the reference made it start working.

Comment: As I included in the screenshot, I already added System.Data.Linq.
I also tried the Copy Local=True part but still not working.

Comment: Missing the [source citation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757637/cannot-find-using-system-data-linq) in this answer, it's a brief summary of the 2 highest voted answers

Comment: **Sorry i am new this. I will take care next time** @TimSchmelter