# LINQ to SQL, 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data'

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I tried to connect my project to a database, using LINQ to SQL, following a few online guides. I created a simple database `Library`, added new `LINQ to SQL Classes` item in the project, named `SimpleLibraryDatabase`, connected to the server and dragged the required tables. So far no problems, but when i tried to build the solution, it failed. Source of the problem appears to be in the auto-generated file `SimpleLibraryDatabase.designer.cs`, where it gives me over 70 errors, most of them saying:

```
The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

What is also weird for me, in this generated context class, there is no constructor, that takes 0 arguments, unlike in all the tutorials I've watched.

This is my first time playing with databases in C#.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757637/cannot-find-using-system-data-linq

Comment: No, the System.Data.Linq doesn't appear in the reference manager

Comment: Could it be because i've created the LINQ to SQL in the class library project? Cause when i did it in the WPF project, everything is fine.

Comment: I changed the framework to .NET Framework 4.8 and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ to SQL is a component of .NET Framework version 3.5, It's just available on  .NET Framework 3.5 ~ 4.8 and not accessible to classes in the .Net core.

> LINQ to SQL is a component of .NET Framework version 3.5 that provides a run-time infrastructure for managing relational data as objects.

[Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/)